# Hadamard counterexample Dirichlet-problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Good afternoon,

I try to understand the follwoing counterexample of Hadamard:

The classical solution of
$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = 0 ~~\text{ in }\Omega\\
u=g \text{ auf }~~ \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$

with $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\partial \Omega)$ **not always lies in $H^1(\Omega)$**.

To show this Hadamard took the function
$
\begin{equation}
     u(r, \phi) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{n!}\frac{sin(n! \phi)}{n^2}
\end{equation}
$
in polar-coordinates on $\Omega =$ "the unit-disk". After computing the Laplacian in polar coordinates it was very easy to show that this function is indeed a classical solution (i.e. u harmonic) but now I am supposed to choose an appropriate boundary value function $g \in C(\partial \Omega)$, such that this $u(r,\phi)$ is not in $H^1(\Omega)$. Can someone help? By the way in our lecture we had the statement that harmonic functions have minimal seminorms, perhaps this could be useful.

Comment: In order to satisfy the boundary condition, you have to choose $g = u_{|\partial\Omega}$, don't you?

Comment: Ok if we do that, how do we now see that this $u$ is not in $H^1(\Omega)$? By the way, thanks for your answer!

Comment: I wrote it on paper, it is a bit long. I can make a summary?

Comment: Hi, sorry I was some days away! In the last week I found it out by myself. It was indeed a very long computation, but now it is clear to me. Thank you very much!!!