# Minimizing Dirichlet Energy with Constraints

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I am interested in minimizing the Dirichlet energy

$$E[f]=\iint_{D_1(\mathbf{0})} \|\nabla f\|^2 \mathrm{d}A ,$$

over the unit disk $D_1(\mathbf{0})=\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbf{R}^2:x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq 1\}$ given equality constraints of the form $\{f(\mathbf{x}_n)=y_n:1 \leq n \leq N \}$ with $\|\mathbf{x}_n\|=1$ and $y_n \in \mathbf{R}$.

I know that specifying $f$ on the boundary in full, in terms of a continuous function, determines the solution entirely as the harmonic function given by Poisson's formula

$$f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\theta-t)+r^2}f(\cos t,\sin t) \mathrm{d}t. $$

However, I'm not sure what happens when only a select few boundary values are provided. In summary, I want to solve the following optimization problem:
$$\operatorname{argmin} _f\iint_{x_1^2+x_2^2\leq 1} \|\nabla f(x_1,x_2)\|^2 \mathrm{d}x_1 \mathrm{d}x_2\\ s.t. f(\cos(t_n),\sin(t_n))=y_n, \quad 1 \leq n \leq N. $$

---

**My attempt:**

Obviously if there is only one constraint $f(\mathbf{x}_1)=y_1$ the solution is the constant function $f(x_1,x_2) \equiv y_1$.

I've also managed to express the Dirichlet energy in smaller disks as a quadratic form of the boundary values:

$$E_R[f]=\iint_{D_R(\mathbf{0})} \|\nabla f\|^2 \mathrm{d}A = \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{4 \pi R^2 \left( (1+R^4) \cos(t_1-t_2)-2R^2 \right)}{\left(1-2R^2 \cos(t_1-t_2)+R^4\right)^2} f(\cos t_1, \sin t_1) f(\cos t_2, \sin t_2)\mathrm{d}t_1 \mathrm{d}t_2. $$
Here $0 \leq R < 1$, and unfortunately a straightforward limit $R \to 1$ appears to make the integral divergent.

Letting $$K(t_1-t_2):=\frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \frac{4 \pi R^2 \left( (1+R^4) \cos(t_1-t_2)-2R^2 \right)}{\left(1-2R^2 \cos(t_1-t_2)+R^4\right)^2},$$
I computed the variational derivative with respect to $f$ and found the condition
$$\int_0^{2\pi} K(\tau-t) f(\cos t, \sin t) \equiv 0, \quad \text{ for all } \tau.$$

I am stuck here as I don't know how to use the constraints in this variational approach.

Any help on solving the problem with more than 1 constraint would be greatly appreciated. I would love to have the solution of the most general problem, but if that's too hard, special cases such as boundary values given on the vertices of a regular polygon would also be informative. Thanks.

Comment: I am baffled by this problem. In which class of functions are you trying to minimize the Dirichlet energy? Usually, this is done in the Sobolev space $H^1(D)$, but elements in this space are not functions but equivalence classes of functions, so prescribing the value at a single point makes no sense. You can prescribe the trace of a Sobolev function, but again you assign an equivalence class, not a function. If you work in $C^1(D)$, then you are not guaranteed the minimum exists.

Comment: @Gio67 I would be happy with the function class $C(\partial D)$, as Poisson's formula would allow me to extend the solution to the open disk. So, out of all continuous functions on the unit circle, satisfying the all of the constraints, is there any particular one for which the harmonic extension attains the infimum of the unit disk Dirichlet energies? That set of energies is bounded below by 0, and is non empty, as linearly interpolating the constraints is an admissible function. If it can be proven that this problem has no solution, that is also good enough for me. Is this clearer now?

Comment: Maybe you'll find interesting to have a look to the so called Prym-Hadamard counterexample: it is similar to the one constructed by Hidde in his answer below (which I have upvoted). There is also a [relevant question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800778/hadamard-counterexample-dirichlet-problem): in practice it says that there exist several harmonic functions with continuous boundary value for which the Dirichlet integral  is $\infty$ (Prym proved this result originally for harmonic functions with *discontinuous* boundary value).

Comment: ... (**Continued from my former comment**) This implies that your approach, despite seeming perfectly correct, will fail for infinitely many functions with reasonable boundary values. This implies also that this is not the route chosen for the solution of PDEs admitting a potential functional by the direct method in the calculus of variation. Well, my two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the variational problem does not have a solution unless $y_1=\ldots = y_N$, in which case the solution is constant. The reason is that functions with singularities exist in $W^{1,2}$, meaning that we can satisfy the conditions at the boundary points, with arbitrarily little cost in terms of the $L^2$-norm of the gradient.

Let me sketch the idea for $N=2$, and $y_1=1$ and $y_2=0$ (and $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2$ arbitrary). The general case can be done similarly, although slightly more involved. We consider for $\epsilon>0$ the continuous function $$f_{\epsilon}:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \quad f_{\epsilon}(x) = \begin{cases} 1-c_\epsilon+\log\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|+\epsilon}\right)\right) & \text{when $|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|\leq \frac{1}{\exp(\exp(c_\epsilon-1))-1}-\epsilon$},\\ 0 & \text{else,} \end{cases}$$ where $c_\epsilon = \log(\log(1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}))$. Note that $c_\epsilon \to \infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, and hence, we have that $f_{\epsilon}(\mathbf{x}_1)=1=y_1$ and $f_{\epsilon}(\mathbf{x}_2)=0=y_2$ for $\epsilon$ small enough. Since $u(x) = \log(\log(1+\frac{1}{|x|})) \in W^{1,2}_{loc}$, we deduce that $$\|\nabla f_{\epsilon}\|_{L^2(D_1(\mathbf{0}))}\leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(D_{r_\epsilon}(\mathbf{0}))} \to 0 \quad \text{as $\epsilon \to 0$},$$ with $r_{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{\exp(\exp(c_\epsilon-1))-1}-\epsilon \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. This implies that the infimum of the variational problem is zero, which is not attained since constant functions do not satisfy the boundary condition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is good to know about the $W^{1,2}$ case. As commented above I am more interested in the continuous case, however.

Comment: @user1337 But the functions $f_{\epsilon}$ that I have constructed are continuous, so they are admissible for your problem. This shows that the infimum is zero even over the continuous functions, and hence, only constant solutions exists.

Comment: Sorry I misread here. You appear to be correct.